# Inserting Memberpress Rule into Elementor

Tags: elementor, learnpress, memberpress

I'm looking to protect Elementor content with a Memberpress Rule. I created a partial rule which provided a shortcode + PHP snippet. The shortcode widget doesn't seem to be protecting the content.

Any advice on how I can protect a block with this partial rule?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cc0cc.jpg

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I am having the same issue.